# pyautogui scroll and dragto are inconsistent depending on the size of the scrollbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, scroll, pyautogui

### Problem:

##### PyAutoGUI scrolls a different amount depending on the size of the scrollbar. I would like to scroll the same amount of pixels, no matter the size of the scrollbar

---

This window has 27 boxes total. As you can see, scrolling a total of 90 pixels moves us passed 5 boxes and perfectly lines the top of the 6th box with the header

[image]

This is the intended outcome: the top of the box should be perfectly lined up with the header

[image]

Take a different scrollable area now. This one has 29 boxes total. I scroll the same 90 pixels but  to top of the box is cut off! This is not the desired outcome

[image]

---

#### Notes:

- Dragging the scrollbar straight down instead of diagonally (like in the gif) doesn't make a difference
- Scrolling in the window instead of dragging the scroll bar produces the same results

Here is the code that I use to actually do the scrolling. I created a helper function to test both that aren't working

```
import pyautogui as pag
import pydirectinput as pdi
from time import sleep

def stats_scroll(scroll, *, drag=True, time=.2):
    # this is where the mouse should be
    scrollbar_y_pos = 450

    if drag:
        # drag the scrollbar the specified amount
        sleep(.1)
        pdi.moveTo(1800, scrollbar_y_pos)
        sleep(.1)
        pag.dragTo(1900, scrollbar_y_pos + scroll, time, button='left')
        sleep(2)
    else:
        # scroll down the specified amount
        sleep(.1)
        pag.scroll(-scroll)
        sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the scrollbar's length depends on the size of the content being scrolled and on the size of scrollview itself.

In your example, you only have 30ish boxes in your scrollview. Now, let's think about how it would be if you had 1000 boxes:

Scrolling by exactly 90 pixels will scroll way more than 5 boxes, maybe a few dozens.

One way to deal with this problem would be to either:

1. Use the keyboard in order to navigate in the menu itself. You won't need to know how many pixels you need to scroll per box.
2. If you don't have the luxury of being able to navigate with a keyboard in this GUI, I would do this:

Create a while loop that will scroll until it finds a specific item in the scrollview.

You are using `pyautogui` so you could use this to locate this item (you will need to take a screenshot of it and specify its path):

```py
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("some_image.png")
pyautogui.click(x, y)
...
```

When you find the item you can then exit out of the while loop or do your stuff and then continue search for the next item.

---

### Update

Here is another simple solution which might work.
I made this table in order to show you the reasoning:

|  | Case 1 | Case 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Number of pixels to move 5 boxes | 90 | = 90 * 29 / 27 = 96.7 pixels |
| Number of pixels to move 1 box | 90/5 = 18 | = (90/5) * 29 / 27 = 19.3 pixels |
| Number of boxes in scroll view | 27 | 29 |

Note that you will have to find a way to deal with the fact that sometimes you might need to scroll by 0.3 pixels (less than a pixel). You cannot assume that 1 box is exactly 19 pixels for a scroll view containing 29 boxes. It should be fine if you only need to scroll once to the Nth box but you will start to observe an offset if you were to make multiple scrolls in a row.

You could use a variable to store the decimal part you don't take you don't take:

```py
decimal_offset = 0 # This is the variable

def compute_amount_scroll(nb_cells_in_scroll_view, nb_cells_to_scrollby):
    global decimal_offset
    nb_pixels_per_box = nb_cells_in_scroll_view * (90/5) / 27
    nb_pixels_to_scrollby = nb_cells_to_scrollby * nb_pixels_per_box

    decimal_offset += nb_pixels_to_scrollby - int(nb_pixels_to_scrollby)

    # This is where we will deal with the decimals we accumulate over time (multiple scrolls in a row)
    if decimal_offset > 1:
        nb_pixels_to_scrollby += int(decimal_offset)
        decimal_offset -= int(decimal_offset)

    return int(nb_pixels_to_scrollby)

# Scroll 5 boxes 
scroll = compute_amount_scroll(29, 5)
stats_scroll(scroll)

# Scroll 10 other boxes after that
scroll = compute_amount_scroll(29, 10)
stats_scroll(scroll)
...
```

But you should also bear in mind that the size of this scroll view depends on the size of your screen/window itself. You should find a way to deal with that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the analogy about a scroll view with 1000 boxes makes a lot of sense and really helped me. The solution that I am going with is having different fixed scroll amounts depending on the # of boxes. Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my answer. I think this method works best (I didn't get to try it sadly). Please mark this answer as `accepted` if it solved your problem. Have a great day @NicholasHansen-Feruch